# Assigning custom colors to Plotly legend

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-python

I am working with this csv file:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsX2n.png
and it contains star colors as red, blue,white,etc. However, when I plot it with plotly using this code:

```
import plotly_express as px
df = pd.read_csv('/Users/rachanajoshi/Dropbox/Mac/Desktop/stars.csv')
fig = px.scatter(df , x = "Temperature (K)" , y="Luminosity(L/Lo)" ,
                    size = "Radius(R/Ro)",
                     
                    )
fig.show()
```

plotly_express assigns generic colors to it in a random fashion, like this-
[image: here's the image how it appears when I plot it]

How can I plot this graph with the specific colors given written in the 6th column 'Star color'??

Thank you so much

Comment: The function `px.scatter()` has the keyword `color` to pass colors. Read more [here](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.scatter).

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use color keyword (as @mosc9575 mentioned) and map colors from your csv table, something like that:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import OrderedDict
import plotly_express as px
df = pd.read_csv('1.csv')

df_colors = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(df["Star color"]))

colors_dict = {"Red":"red",
"Blue White":"#F4F5FF",
"White":"white",
"Yellowish White":"white",
"Blue white":"#F4F5FF",
"Pale yellow orange":"yellow",
"Blue":"blue",
"Blue ":"blue",
"Blue-white":"#F4F5FF",
"Blue-white ":"#F4F5FF",
"Blue white ":"#F4F5FF",
"Whitish":"white",
"yellow-white":"yellow",
"Orange":"orange",
"White-Yellow":"yellow",
"white":"white",
"Blue":"blue",
"yellowish":"yellow",
"Yellowish":"yellow",
"Orange-Red":"red",
"Blue white":"#F4F5FF",
"Blue-White":"#F4F5FF"
}

plotly_colors = [colors_dict[c] for c in df_colors]
print(plotly_colors)

fig = px.scatter(df , x = "Temperature (K)" , y="Luminosity(L/Lo)" ,
                    size = "Radius(R/Ro)",
                    color="Star color",
                    color_discrete_sequence=plotly_colors,
                    )
fig.show()
```

Result:
[image]
ps. set color values you want in **colors_dict**

Comment: @MjO7 you may now accept the answer https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stackoverflow